# Machine Learning Python output predictions

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, verbose

I have some code to analysis and predictions data sets. In my code predictiosn are onlt 0 or 1 but in my data.csv I have from 1 to 7 output. In verbose mode output can be 0 or 1. How can I solve problem to predict output as 3,4 etc.

Here is my data set **first 10 row**:

> ```
> 1,2,4,4,1,1,3
> 1,2,4,4,1,2,1
> 1,2,4,4,1,3,2
> 1,2,4,4,2,1,3
> 1,2,4,4,2,2,2
> 1,2,4,4,2,3,4
> 1,2,4,4,3,1,3
> 1,2,4,4,3,2,2
> 1,2,4,4,3,3,4
> 1,2,4,5,1,1,3
> ```

Here is **code** below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from termcolor import cprint
import numpy


dataset = numpy.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\usr6907\\Desktop\\AIData\\data4.csv", delimiter=",")


X = dataset[:1500,0:6]
Y = dataset[:1500,6]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10,  verbose=1)


scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)

print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
print("-"*150)


test_verisi = dataset[1500:1728, 0:6]
predictions = model.predict(test_verisi)
dogru = 0
yanlis = 0
toplam_veri = len(dataset[1500:1728,6])

for x, y in zip(predictions, dataset[1500:1728,6]):    
    x = int(numpy.round(x[0]))
    if int(x) == y:
        cprint("Tahmin: "+str(x)+" - Ger�ek De�er: "+str(int(y)), "white", "on_green", attrs=['bold'])
        dogru += 1
    else:
        cprint("Tahmin: "+str(x)+" - Ger�ek De�er: "+str(int(y)), "white", "on_red", attrs=['bold'])
        yanlis += 1

print("\n", "-"*150, "\nISTATISTIK:\nToplam ", toplam_veri, " Veri i�ersinde;\nDo�ru Bilme Say�s�: ", dogru, "\nYanl�� Bilme Say�s�: ",yanlis,
      "\nBa�ar� Y�zdesi: ", str(int(100*dogru/toplam_veri))+"%", sep=' ')
```

Comment: Your last layer and your loss is not ready for multi-class. I'm afraid you have to get some basics first.

Comment: Your last layer has a sigmoid activation with only a single unit, which means your model is a binary classifier. Depending on whether the outcomes are mutually exclusive or not, you want either a softmax layer with 7 units, or a sigmoid layer with 7 units. This will also affect the choice of loss function. And if you fail to understand that, you should revisit your ML class.